# JQuery Mobile <h1> Titles cut off?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having problem with the title of a header in my jquery code.

Basically after the 3rd character of the title I'm getting ... I'd like to display the whole title.

Why is it cutting it off and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your title will fit in the header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A proper CSS solution is described in point 4 here

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/05/10-handy-jquery-mobile-tips-and-snippets-to-get-you-started/

For list items add:

```
body .ui-li .ui-li-desc {
 white-space: normal;
}
```

For footer content add:

```
body .ui-footer .ui-title {
 white-space: normal;
}
```

Or take a look at this workaround

http://operationmobile.com/how-to-stop-your-jquery-mobile-header-from-being-cut/

Comment: Links may change, you should post the code with a reference to the source for anyone who may be researching this problem in the future.

Comment: I tried this and figuered out that the correct way for a header is to set the CSS like: `.ui-header .ui-title { white-space: normal; }`

Answer (score 7):

Here's the solution I used:

```
<style>
    .ui-header .ui-title {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Note that this probably only works because I don't have anything else in my title bar, such as buttons. If you just use `white-space: normal;` you get text that line wraps, but still takes up two lines. (which is what I was trying to avoid by using `margin-*`.)

Comment: Thanks, though putting it on `.ui-title` or using `<h3 style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">` seems to be sufficient too!